# Trying to compare img alt tags with Playwright

Tags: reactjs, testing, next.js, playwright, playwright-test

I have a Next app with a carousel on my home page.  I am trying to test with Playwright.  I want to get the initial alt text, click right to navigate, and then compare the current alt text to the initial alt text to verify the image did change.  I have tried all manner of comparing the alt text to include asserting the initial alt text after the move and have not been successful so far.

This is the component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSwipeable } from "react-swipeable";

import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

import Button from "../button/button";

import useWindowSize from "../../hooks/useWindowSize";

import { BsDot, BsChevronRight, BsChevronLeft } from "react-icons/bs";

import styles from "./carousel.module.css";

export default function Carousel(data) {
  const [selectedCarousel, setSelectedCarousel] = useState(0);
  const carouselData = data.data;
  const deviceType = useWindowSize();

  const handlers = useSwipeable({
    onSwipedLeft: () => scrollCarousel("right"),
    onSwipedRight: () => scrollCarousel("left"),
  });

  const toggleCarousel = (id) => {
    setSelectedCarousel(id);
  };

  const scrollCarousel = (direction) => {
    if (direction == "right" && selectedCarousel < carouselData.length - 1) {
      setSelectedCarousel(selectedCarousel + 1);
    } else if (direction == "left" && selectedCarousel > 0) {
      setSelectedCarousel(selectedCarousel - 1);
    } else if (direction == "right") {
      setSelectedCarousel(0);
    } else if (direction == "left") {
      setSelectedCarousel(carouselData.length - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container} {...handlers} data-testid="carousel" id="carousel">
        <Image
          src={carouselData[selectedCarousel].imgUrl}
          alt={carouselData[selectedCarousel].altText}
          width="600px"
          height="300px"
          layout="responsive"
          loading="lazy"
        />
        {deviceType === "computer" ? (
          <>
            <BsChevronLeft
              className={styles.left}
              onClick={() => scrollCarousel("left")}
            />
            <BsChevronRight
              className={styles.right}
              onClick={() => scrollCarousel("right")}
            />
          </>
        ) : null}
        <div className={styles.carouselBtn}>
          <Button
            text={carouselData[selectedCarousel].buttonText}
            url={carouselData[selectedCarousel].buttonLink}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.selector}>
        {carouselData.map((data) => (
          <span key={data.id}>
            <BsDot
              className={`${styles.dot} ${
                selectedCarousel === data.id ? styles.selectedDot : null
              }`}
              onClick={() => toggleCarousel(data.id)}
            />
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is my most recent attempt

```
test.describe("Mobile Homepage", () => {
  test.use({ viewport: { width: 390, height: 844}})
  test("has swipeable carousel", async ({page}) => {
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/')
    await expect(page.getByAltText("Test alt text 1")).toBeVisible()
    const center = { x: 195, y: 200}
    await page.mouse.move(center.x + 50,center.y)
    await page.mouse.down();
    await page.mouse.move(center.x - 50,center.y)
    await page.mouse.up()
    await expect(page.getByAltText("Test alt text 3")).toBeVisible()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also add the sample `data` prop for this test? Are you sure the center calculation is actually over whatever you're trying to click? Maybe try `page.click()` rather than doing this by hand with pixels.